# To insert blank space between the rows

Tags: excel

In the below Excel sheet I have three columns:

```
column1   |   column2   |  column3
----------------------------------
  A       |     small   |  blue
  B       |     med     |  yellow
  C       |     large   |  green
  D       |     large   |  green
```

How may I insert blank rows between each of the rows?

Comment: can you not insert row?

Comment: @ZAT Yes You are right 3 columns

Comment: @ZAT There are 1000 rows is there is possibility of adding blank row in between each row?

Comment: you should use tag vba or excel-vba while asking solution with code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to VBA there are various non-VBA ways to achieve what I understand you to want. Assuming `column1` is in A1 of Sheet1, in another sheet in A1, copied across to C1 and then all three formulae copied down to suit:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()+1,2)=0,OFFSET(Sheet1!A$1,INT(ROW()/2),),"")
```

[IF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php)
[MOD](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mod.php)
[OFFSET](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php)
[INT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/int.php)
[ROW](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/row.php)